# In R, is there any way to properly transfer the Chinese time character from 12-hour-setting into 24-hour-setting?

Tags: r, lubridate

I use `lubridate` to do the transformation. It is good to support the English characters but not Chinese ones. For example,

```
> library(lubridate)
> mdy_hm("01/31/2017 08:01 PM")
[1] "2017-01-31 20:01:00 UTC"
> mdy_hm("01/31/2017 08:01 AM")
[1] "2017-01-31 08:01:00 UTC"
```

It is clear to separate the "AM" and "PM" conditions. But for the another example,

```
> ymd_hm("2017年9月10日上午12:36")
[1] "2017-09-10 12:36:00 UTC"
```

It can't transfer the "AM" condition into the "PM" condition.

---

Thx @ycw, It works for me. Here, I write a function.

```
Tconv <- function(x){
  time = x
  y <- ifelse(grepl("日 上午", time), paste(time, "AM", sep = " "), 
              ifelse(grepl("日 下午", time), paste(time, "PM", sep = " "), 
                     time))
  z <- lubridate::ymd_hm(y)
  return(z)
}

> time <- data_frame(date = "2017年9月10日 上午12:36", "2017年9月10日 下午12:36")
> Tconv(time)
[1] "2017-09-10 00:36:00 UTC" "2017-09-10 12:36:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

If `上午` means "AM", you can use `grepl` to detect if this string exists, and if `TRUE`, add "AM" to that string.

```
library(lubridate)

time <- c("2017年9月10日上午12:36")

time2 <- ifelse(grepl("上午", time), paste(time, "AM", sep = " "), time)
ymd_hm(time2)
[1] "2017-09-10 00:36:00 UTC"
```

Comment: @Jiaxiang I am glad it works. Please accept my post as the answer.